# How to get a subset of columns from a table without requiring a new type in Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-6

e.g. If I have the following class:

```
public class Schema
{
    public int SchemaId { get; set; }
    public byte[] XsdFile { get; set; }
    public byte[] MetadataFile { get; set; }
    public byte[] TemplateFile { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I use this query in Linq, I will get all the columns:

```
from s in db.Schemas select s;
```

If I need only the `Id` and `Name` column and default values for other three byte array fields, I will need to either project it to another defined type or anonymous type or dictionary like this:

```
db.Schemas.ToDictionary(s => s.SchemaId, s => s.Name);
```

But, How can I get the same type i.e. `Schema` itself with a LINQ query that will have default values of these byte arrays rather than fetching them from the table? I don't really want to create another type and I can't do with anonymous type because I want to transfer it from web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the relevant pieces into anonymous types, call `.ToList()` to bring the data into memory, then project into new Schema objects.

```
var result = (from s in db.Schemas
             select new { s.SchemaId, s.Name })
             .ToList()
             .Select(s => new Schema
             { 
                 SchemaId = s.SchemaId, 
                 Name = s.Name,
                 XsdFile = new byte[length],
                 MetadataFile = new byte[length],
                 TemplateFile = new byte[length]
             });
```

Comment: This will throw an exception that - The entity or complex type 'Schema' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @teenup You mention LINQ to Entities here and Linq to Sql in the other answer, which is it?

Comment: This is `Linq to Sql` - I mentioned word `from table` in the question heading also

Comment: @teenup, I wasn't aware you couldn't create an entity object inside the query, guess I've never had the need to do it.  This seems to work in LinqPad.

Comment: @teenup, also, when you mention `from table` that doesn't necessarily mean anything.  Linq to SQL and Linq to Entities are different.

Comment: Ok, but this is also throwing exception: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @teenup, Updated.  Try this one.  We have to pull the results back into memory before calling `make()`.

Comment: I am still getting the same exception: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @teenup, try splitting the `from` statement into two and verify that you can do the first select.  Then, the second select.  I don't know why you would get that error on the second select, because at that point it should just be Linq to Objects.

Comment: I am using this with Oracle Managed Data Access Entity Framework 6. If I use `.ToList()` after first select, only then it works, otherwise this same exception: 'Invoke' is not supported.

Comment: @teenup, Updated.  Adding .ToList between the two Select statements works for me in Linq to Entities with SQL Server.  If it is different for Oracle, then I'm not sure what the answer is.  Also, you don't really need the make `Func` if the ToList call solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Split the routine into two.

First use an anonymous type

```
var tempList= (from s in db.Schemas select new { s.SchemaId , s.Name}).ToList();
```

Then use the temporary List to create objects o type Schema

```
var results = (from s in tempList 
              select new Schema { Schema = s.SchemaId , Name = s.Name }
              ).ToList();
```